# android custom listview row doesn't match seen on phone/emulator

Tags: android, android-listview

I am currently running into issues with my custom listview layout. I got what I thought would be the hardest part finished with the custom adapter. All the data is there it just doesn't look the way it does in the XML. Both on a phone and emulator.

Example (Ignore the borders. The yellow is the row)

What the XML file looks like. [image: Should be...]

What it is rendering as.

[image: What I see]

My XML file for the custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:maxHeight="30dp" 
    android:background="@color/yellow" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/blankuser"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="username"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Clout: "
        android:textColor="@color/dgreen"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/dgreen"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:text=">"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:text="score"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My getView for the adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        LeaderView ldrView = null;

        if(rowView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlist, null);
            ldrView = new LeaderView();
            ldrView.username = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ldrView.hometown = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ldrView.score = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
//          ldrView.avatar = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ldrView.ranking = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            ldrView.clout = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            rowView.setTag(ldrView);
        } else {
            ldrView = (LeaderView) rowView.getTag();
        }
        LeaderList currentLeader = (LeaderList) leaders.get(position);
        ldrView.username.setText(currentLeader.getUsername());
        ldrView.hometown.setText(currentLeader.getHometown());
        ldrView.score.setText(currentLeader.getScore());
        ldrView.ranking.setText(currentLeader.getRanking());
        ldrView.clout.setText(currentLeader.getClout());
        return rowView;
    }
```

Thanks in advanced!

EDIT:

Got it working. It was a bug with the picture or the package. I had to clean the package, delete R.java, and delete the imageView. After readding the imageView and building it looks like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be an issue with the `imageView`. I deleted and re-added it to the XML and it's working as desired. Thanks for the help and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the "Clout: " portion of the view in code, which won't render in the eclipse editor.  Set some default text for the clout and it should match up with the device's rendering.  That view is what's causing the issue, most likely.

Comment: All of the textViews have default text. The style is set to italics so it won't render in eclipse. The issue I am talking about it the space above and below the image.

Comment: Because it won't render in eclipse, it won't add the right padding or margins.  Try fixing it without the italics on, so it renders, then change the italics after.

Comment: Still happening without the italics. I tested and made the relativeLayout height=20dp and it squished everything. I ran the app and it shows on my phone exactly the same. There must be someone in my custom adapter that I can set the height or something that is overriding the XML height.

Comment: Any other ideas by chance please?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this site,, its good for your reference ::
http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android7dvancedListViewB.php#CustomListView